# C++ uniform initialization with default values

Tags: c++, c++11

Considering following structs:

```
struct A
{
    int i;
};

struct B
{
    int i = 0;
};
```

Why I can initialize objects of type A using uniform initializers and I can't initialize objects of type B?

```
A a{1};
B b{1}; //ill formed
```

What is the compiler doing when a default value is used to initialize members?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++11, `B` is not an aggregate by virtue of having an equal initializer for a non-static data member. This means you cannot use brace-enclosed initializers unless you provide a suitable constructor.

This restriction has been relaxed in C++14. In that standard, `B` is an aggregate and the initialization is valid.